# Using vaadin add-on "EasyUpload" - compile widgetset with maven

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm new of vaadin and this is the first time that I try to use an add-on [EasyUpload add-on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDI59.png)

I'm using maven to build my project, and i modified my pom.xml in ths way:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>My-vaadin-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Add-On Repository -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>easyuploads</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>

</project>
```

But when to try

> MultiFileUpload

i get the following result:

[image]

I read the I should compile my widget-set, but I don't use a custom widget-set, I'm using a default widget-Set.

This is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>



    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myApplication.AutowiringApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI class to use</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myApplication.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>   

    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>VaadinApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Where am I doing wrong?
How to can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a widgetset in the src/main/resources folder under an arbitrary package (x.y for example). Name it `AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml` for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari"/>  

    <inherits name="org.vaadin.easyuploads.Widgetset" />
</module>
```

Annotate your custom UI with the following:

```
@Widgetset("x.y.AppWidgetSet")
```

The "inherits" part is autogenerated by the `mvn vaadin:update-widgetset` goal based on the dependencies of your pom. Since I included the multifileupload here you don't need to call it this time.

Do a `mvn vaadin:compile`.
Refresh your project and your server.

Comment: When i run mvn vaadin:compile i get     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.1.12:compile (default-cli) on project myApp: GWT Module com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Did you annotate your UI with the @Widgetset?

Comment: Thanks now everything works, but i run mvn vaadin:update-widgetset that has replaced <inherits name="com.wcs.wcslib.vaadin.widget.multifileupload.MultiFileUploadWidgetSet" /> with  <inherits name="org.vaadin.easyuploads.Widgetset" />

Comment: It's ok, I thought you are using the MultiFileUpload which is another addon. You should check it :) https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/multifileupload:vaadin

Comment: Now I'm using multifileupload addon, but I'm not able to find some examples about this. Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but I only know of the examples in the addon page. You should check out the source code from github, then you can figure it out from the javadoc/source. The addon page links to the github project.

Answer (score 1):

When you use addon widgets, you will have to recompile the whole widget set.
Depending on your maven targets there should exist one such...